# Some errors occur on fresh installed windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

First, here's my machine's specifications (refer below)

**Motherboard**: [GA H81M DS2 REV3](http://www.gigabyte.ph/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5182#ov),
**Processor**: [Intel core i3 4170](http://ark.intel.com/products/77490/Intel-Core-i3-4170-Processor-3M-Cache-3_70-GHz),
**Graphics card**: [GTX 950 2GB GDDR5 128bit](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/GTX-950-2GD5T-OC.html#hero-overview),
**RAM**: [16GB (2 x 8GB) Kingston HyperX Fury (black)](http://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/memory/fury)

with fresh installed windows 7 and complete system drivers such as GTX 950 latest driver installed and then I got this error on desktop (finish boot and windows has been load)

[image: error image]

and this when I tried to run **windows experience index**

[image]

all my games run in no problem, yet if I remove my graphics card and hook the VGA cord to the onboard VGA output, no errors prompting, any ideas, help please? what seems the causes? how can I fix this? I have not tried changing OS yet (windows 7 to windows 10).

Comment: You say "fresh installed" in your title. Have you installed ALL of the Windows Updates? How about firmware updates for the GTX 950? Or rolling the drivers for the GTX 950 back to the previous version?

Comment: "faulting module name" points to the nVIDIA driver. report it to nVIDIA (support or via forum)

Comment: @CharlieRB: Yes, I have installed the possible windows update and tried to roll back to previous nvidia drivers for GTX 950 but still the error persist, anyway, I have tried switching to windows 10 and seems the error is gone.

Comment: @magicandre1981: That's also my guest, anyway, I have tried to switch to windows 10 and the error is not prompting anymore.

Comment: the winsat tool is hidden since Windows 8.1, because the index was never really useful.